# Get only the grandchildren, not the direct children of page/current page?

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach, wordpress-theming

I know javascript pretty well now but I am new to php and wordpress theme building. I have searched a fair bit and can't find a solution to something that seems like a pretty simple task, all I would like to accomplish is get all the grandchildren of a page only, not the direct children, like so:

**Portfolio**

- child 1

  - grandchild 1A
  - grandchild 1B
- child 2

  - grandchild 2A
  - grandchild 2B

My page is "Portfolio" and I would like to "get_pages" but only the ones that are grandchildren of "Portfolio, so in this case it would return only: -"grandchild 1A", "grandchild 1B", "grandchild 2A", "grandchild 2B".

```
<?php
$portfolio = get_pages( array( 
   'child_of' => $post->ID));

       foreach( $portfolio as $page ) { 
       //My idea here was to check if the page that is being looped through, was a direct child of portfolio, if so then it would skip it.
         if($page !== 'child_of' => $post) {    
         echo $page->post_title; 
              }
       }?>
```

any suggestions?

**EDIT:**

```
<?php
$grandchildren = get_pages( array( 'child_of' => $portfolioPageId ) );
foreach( $grandchildren as $grandchild ) {
if($grandchild->post_parent != $portfolioPageId ){   

    echo $grandchild->post_title; 

}}?>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some hints on writing a good-quality question.

Comment: Okay, I updated my question with what I have so far.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this code that uses the `child_of` parameter to get the portfolio page ID and excludes the pages with the `post_parent` equals to your portfolio page ID.

```
<?php
$grandchildren = get_pages( array( 'child_of' => $portfolioPageId ) );
foreach( $grandchildren as $grandchild ) {
    if($grandchild->post_parent != $portfolioPageId ){   
        // Whatever you need
    }
}
```

Comment: That just gets the child pages... which is what he did not want - he wants the child pages of the pages your code will list. You could use your code to store the child page ids - and then loop through them with the same code referencing the ids as the child_of parameter but im not sure how elegant a solution that would be :)

Comment: Have a look [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages), it says that _Lists the sub-pages of a single Page only; uses the ID for a Page as the value. Defaults to 0 (list all Pages). **Note that the child_of parameter will also fetch "grandchildren" of the given ID, not just direct descendants.**_

Comment: Yeah it gets the child pages as well - thats the problem - the solution needs a way to exclude them

Comment: isn't the `$grandchild->post_parent != $portfolioPageId` solving the problem? if you get all the children and grandchildren and exclude the pages with the `post_parent` equal to the `$portfolioPageId` you should only have the grandchildren

Comment: I think I missed a large chunk (the if statment) of your code... yes thats it, let me mark it as useful now

Comment: Thanks @SimonPollard if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this. Also if you need something else, please feel free to ask

Comment: Not my question @IlGala else I would - hopefully he will read it and use it :)

Comment: I want to up vote that comment :p Glad its not just me, I hope @William-Larsen-Bang reads your answer now :)

Comment: Okay I tried this out, in advance thank you guys so much, I pasted what my code looks like now in the "EDIT" now it echos all the children, including the ones we are trying to exclude? Anyone else tried if theirs are working with a similar setup, because mine isn't xD

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JS then you can use `querySelectorAll`. Which will give you back all the grand child nodes. You may use it such:

```
var getNodes = document.querySelectorAll("grandparent > parent grandchild");
```

Comment: Hello moomdid. Thanks for your contribution on SO. Please consider using formatting tools while answering. They make your answers look more readable. You can re-format your answer by clicking the edit button right now.